# Is there anyway that I could select the element which width is defined fixed?

Tags: jquery

Suppose, I have the following css

```
div{width: 1000px; height: 100px; background-color: #f00;}
div.nextst{width: 1000px; height: 200px; background-color: #ff0;}
div.nextsty{width: 200px; height: 300px; background-color: #fff;}
```

I would like to select those divs which width is 1000 pixels. How can I select the selector with jquery?

Comment: IMHO: use a separate class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think there's a specific selector for that, but you can use this :

```
$('div').filter(function() {
    return $(this).css('width') == '1000px';
});
```

EDIT :

If you want to do it more than once and you think it's worth it, you can define a custom selector :

```
$.expr[':'].width = function(obj, index, meta){
    return $(obj).css('width') == meta[3];
};
```

This allows you to select your objects easily like this :

```
$("div:width('1000px')").css("width", "800px");
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qjTFY/)

Comment: Does this return of whole body css which width is 1000px?

Comment: I want to change all width 1000px to 800px;

Comment: @C-Link : then just add `.css('width', '800px');` after the filter function.

Comment: @C-Link - no, like this: `$('div').filter(function() {
    return $(this).css('width') == '1000px';
}).css('width', '800px');`

Comment: I tried doing as your edited method too but in my localhost working wrongly but in jsfiddle working correctly as http://jsfiddle.net/qjTFY/2/ in my localhost the subtracted width is not working properly, anything wrong there?

Comment: I came to know when I set background-image it's not working properly but when I set background-color it's working properly. What can I do?